# TryParsing User Input for an Attribute

Tags: c#, object, attributes, console-application, user-input

Simple quesiton I can't seem to find an answer to. Essentially, this attribute to this object is a `Char` and I need to `TryParse` it to make sure that it doesn't throw an error when the user inputs something. My teacher hasn't taught us a `get` and `set` (I think is what it's called?), so I have to use a `TryParse`. I also have a double and an integer but that's besides the point. I know I have to start with this, and I tried doing

```
employee1._gender = char.TryParse(InputUtilities.GetStringCharValue("Gender: "), out employee1._gender);
```

and it throws a boolean error, which confuses me. I'm new to classes so I apologize if this is a stupid question. Thank you for all fo your help everyone!

```
    employee1._gender = InputUtilities.GetStringCharValue("Gender: ");
```

Comment: what is the datatype of _gender in employee1?

Comment: `it throws a boolean error`. `TryParse` returns a `bool` type indicating whether the parse succeeded or not. `_gender ` is most likely of type `char` and not `bool`, the types are mismatching. Also `this attribute to this object is a char`, do you mean `field`? `attribute` has a different meaning.

Comment: Possibly, I apologize. ._gender is a char data type and yes it is a field, I apologize for mixing the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close, you are just confusing the error code returned by the TryParse with the out parameter which will be the target of the function call. This is a quick example, be aware that any char provided will be considered valid (i.e. Q):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee employee1 = new Employee();

        Console.Write("Gender: ");

        String userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        if (char.TryParse(userInput, out employee1.gender))
            Console.WriteLine("Ok, you specified: " + employee1.gender);
        else 
            Console.WriteLine("Not valid character: " + userInput); 

        employee1.Print();
    }

    public class Employee {
        public char gender = '?';

        public void Print() {
            Console.WriteLine("Gender is = " + gender);
        }
    }
```

As soon as you learn about getter and setter for a class refactor your code to put all your logic there, that's the beauty of encapsulation in OOP.

Comment: Just came back to this answer and I can't even believe I asked this question haha. Thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome :-) Accept the answer to mark solved the ticket if you are good now.